# How to compare two RDDs in Spark, when data of second stream may not yet be available?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am working on a Spark app that streams data from two different topics `topic_a` and `topic_b` of a Kafka server. I want to consume both streams and check if the data coming from both topics is equal.

```
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(batchDuration))
val eventStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](streamingContext, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, consumerConfig))

def start(record: (RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], Time)): Unit = {
    // ...

    def cmp(rddA: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], rddB: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]): Unit = {
        // Do compare...
        // but rddA or rddB may be empty! :-(
    }

    val rddTopicA = rdd.filter(_.topic == 'topic_a')
    val rddTopicB = rdd.filter(_.topic == 'topic_b')
    cmp(rddTopicA, rddTopicB)

}


eventStream.foreachRDD((x, y) => start((x, y)))
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

The problem is that, when comparing both RDDs in `cmp`, one of the RDDs may be empty, as the data stream may not yet be available in Kafka. Is it possible to somehow wait until both RDDs have the same amount of rows and then start the comparison? Or first convert the RDD that has data into a DataSet and then temporarily store it for later comparison?

Comment: Though it's not reliable solution... Try to maintain same offset number for the same message in both topics... Retrieve msg based on offset range in spark streaming and do your comparison

Comment: Hi John, When you are dealing with two different events having dependencies is not a good design. Consider saving the two streams to a table and operate basing on the available snapshot or basing on your needs.